# Android Dialog imageView out of position at start up

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, picasso, android-glide

Currently an image dialog loads up when an item is pressed. However, whenever the activity is first started, the image loaded is not in the center. It always loads to the top left corner of the screen **only** during the item is first pressed.

For some reason, when I repress the items after, it loads perfectly in the center as I wanted to. But when I reopen the activity, it does the same thing again.

Does anyone have any clue what is going on? My code is:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
                builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

                builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                builder.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://i.imgur.com/45oAm8N.jpg").into(imageView);
                //Glide.with(ChillFragment.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/bbTMZHD.jpg").into(imageView);

                mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                mAttacher.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                        //Outside region
                        if (!mAttacher.getDisplayRect().contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            builder.dismiss();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
```

[image]

Tried changing to

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                builder.addContentView(imageView, Params);
                builder.getWindow().setLayout(Params.width, Params.height);
```

Comment: For some reason, when when I check the values for WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
The lp.height and lp.width is -1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of trying stuff out, turns out there as a bug on the PhotoView library. All I had to do was switch from ImageView to PhotoView.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/issues/320

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rule in the program for the builder. The layout Params that you are using for the image view should also have the rule added that :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(View.WRAP_CONTENT,View.WRAP_CONTENT);
Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTERINPARENT,View.TRUE);
imageView.setLayoutParams(Params);
```

The problem with yours is that it takes the whole screen as the root layout and then inflate the image view. Try using wrap content and then add the rule

Comment: When I used the code above with match parents for the params, it ended up the same. But if i do use wrap content, it does stay in the center, however when I pinch to zoom the image gets cropped.

Comment: Yeah well it will. Y do u even want to pinch zoom in the dialog. Just make a separate window. Else ditch the dialog and make a separate view with touch implementations